# Electric field at an Equipotential surface

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Suppose I have an equipotential surface S. Thus the electric field at each point on said surface is direction normal to the surface.

Will the magnitude of this electric field be constant for all points on this surface?

(This reasoning comes from the feeling that if the electric field strength were to differ, a closed loop path along such field lines may have work done by electric force as non zero)

[image: the purple path has non zero electric work]

I may be wrong, so this is just a small thought.
Thank you.

Comment: The lightning rod is based on the fact that the field is higher at a point than it is on a smooth surface, even when they are at the same potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, usually the electric field will not have the same
magnitude at each point of an equipotential surface.

Here is a simple counter-example (the field
of an electric dipole).
[image]
<sub>(image from [Hyperphysics - Equipotential Lines](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/equipot.html))</sub>

Consider the horizontal equipotential surface in the middle between
the two charges. By definition the potential is constant across this surface.
But the electric field strength is not. Actually it is largest at the
center, but it gets smaller further on the left and further on the right.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right, but there is more to say.

A charge a some point on an equipotential surface will feel an electric force, $q \vec E$, proportional to the field. The force will be in the direction of the field, and toward a region where the charge would have lower potential energy. The change in energy would be $q \vec E \cdot \vec d$.

If you move the charge around (perhaps with a pair of tweezers?) on the surface, its potential energy will not change. The force perpendicular to the movement can change.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite parallel plate capacitor. After charging and disconnection, each plate is at a constant voltage.

But because of the finite size of the capacitor plates, the E field in the centre is about double the E field right at the edge of the plates. So, you guessed wrong.